# Express redirecting but not showing any data?

Tags: node.js, express

I have this router set up:

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    // Get posts data
    db.query("select * from PostSchema", (err, results)=>{
      if(err){
        return res.status(500).end(err.message);
      }
      else{
          res.render('admin/posts', {
            results: results
          });
      }
    });
});
```

The output shows data from MySQL onto my handlebars page. So far so good.

I have another router that posts data:

```
// Post data
router.post('/create', (req, res)=>{

  var {title, status, allowComments, body} = req.body;

  // Execute query
  db.query("INSERT INTO PostSchema (title, status, comments, body) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", [title, status, allowComments, body],(err, results)=>{
    if(err){
      return err;
    }
    else{
      console.log('Post Created!');
      res.render('admin/posts'); // This redirects but does not show any data
    }
  });
});
```

**Problem**

In my first router - it `redirects` me to `'admin/posts'` with `results` data showing in the handlebars.

But, I do the same with the `post` router - it `redirects` me to `'admin/posts'`. But it does not show any data because I am not passing `results`.

**Question**

Is my only option to load the data is

- Do I need to copy all of the code from the first router and stick it into `else` statement in the `post` router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not redirecting to anywhere in your code, all you are doing is sending back some rendered html.

The difference is that you can actually perform redirection instead of just sending back the html in your `POST /create` handler.

When you send redirect response back to client (redirect to `/` in your case). Client will generate another request to that location and your data will be rendered correctly without copying any code to `POST /create` handler.

Use `res.redirect` in your `POST /create` handler like this.

```
// Post data
router.post('/create', (req, res)=>{

  var {title, status, allowComments, body} = req.body;

  // Execute query
  db.query("INSERT INTO PostSchema (title, status, comments, body) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", [title, status, allowComments, body],(err, results)=>{
    if(err){
      return err;
    }
    else{
      console.log('Post Created!');
      res.redirect(303, '/'); 
    }
  });
});
```

---

Also note that if there is an error in your `POST /create` handler, the request will hang because you are not sending anything back to client (you are just returning from the function)

```
if(err){
   return err;
}
```

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks for your answer, what does the `301` do?

Comment: Sorry, should have been 303 instead of 301 but it is just a response status code that indicates status of the response to the client. `3xx` means redirection. `2xx` success, `5xx` internal error and so on.

Comment: In terms of my error in `post/create` handler - what would you suggest doing `res.send 404` error?

Comment: 4xx indicates error made by client (404 means asking for resource that doesn't exist). In case there is an error in your `db.query`, that is the server's fault and client will hardly do anything about that so the appropriate status code should be in `5xx` (you can simply use 500 here).